# Instead of 'mysql_fetch_assoc' - Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter. I have read up on active records and completed the following code:

```
header("Content-Type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1
header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0
header("Expires: 0"); // Proxies

$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

fputcsv($output, array('Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3'));

$this->db->select('field_id_1, field_id_2, field_id_3');
$query = $this->db->get('exp_channel_data');    

$rows = $query->result_array();     

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)) fputcsv($output, $row);
```

In the `while` statement at the end of this code block, I am not sure what to use instead of `mysql_fetch_assoc`.

I have outputted the database results into the variable `$rows`.

What should be used to replace `mysql_fetch_assoc` in the `while` statement?

Thank you.

Comment: `$rows` is an array.  Loop over it: `foreach($rows as $row)`.

Comment: Have a look at the manual.  It explains what you are supposed to do.  https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html

Comment: use foreach as @RocketHazmat said

Comment: why are u generating CSV file manually you can use codeigniter database utilities to generate CSV file really fast check here https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/utilities.html#csv

Answer (score 0):

as you are using result_array(). So $rows give you result in array form and you can use foreach loop to extract data from $rows like foreach($rows as $row).

Comment: It is not the answer he asked.If the result be much big server will not handle it and as @ccdavies said he needs a replacement for mysql_fetch_assoc function which is deprecated in php5 and the advantage of it was reading the Mysql  row by row